# mySQL event for expired posts

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In my table I have a column for expired/active that is a boolean. I basically want to have an event that checks my database every hour for if each row has expired or not based on a date and time, and set the "expired/active" boolean accordingly. What is the best way to do this? I have included some sudo code for clarification.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table_name;

//loop through each row 
//if (row[date] <= today && row[time] <= now) {
    row[expired] = 1;
}
```

I am a little confused about the events and how to use them in php myadmin. mySQL commands are different then php commands so I don't know how to loop through an entire table basically.

Comment: You don't need a loop. Do a bulk update: `UPDATE table_name SET expired = 1 WHERE TIMESTAMP(date, time) <= NOW();`

Comment: You would have a much better time of this keeping your date and time values combined into a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: right now i have date entered in as dd-mm-yyyy and time as hh:mmPM format in 2 separate columns the timestamp doesnt seem to be working... suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Store date and time as a single entity, using an appropriate data type, and don't bother with the event

Comment: I got it working.. thanks! however I'm on a shared hosting plan with hostGator and it wont allow me to turn on the event_scheduler. are there any ways to get around this?